# Android Studio 4.0.1 не может скачать trove4j-20160824.jar при сборке APK

Tags: android-studio

Прошу помощи с Android Studio 4.0.1
При синхронизации проекта генерируется нижеприведённый лог и синхронизация прерывается с ошибкой.

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring root project 'My Application 0003'.
    > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
       > Could not download trove4j-20160824.jar (org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824)
          > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar'.
             > Could not GET 'https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/1917871c8deb468307a584680c87a44572f5a8b0b98c6d397fc0f5f86596dbe7?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22trove4j-20160824.jar%22&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOiBbeyJSZXNvdXJjZSI6Imh0dHAqOi8vZDI5dnprNG93MDd3aTcuY2xvdWRmcm9udC5uZXQvMTkxNzg3MWM4ZGViNDY4MzA3YTU4NDY4MGM4N2E0NDU3MmY1YThiMGI5OGM2ZDM5N2ZjMGY1Zjg2NTk2ZGJlNz9yZXNwb25zZS1jb250ZW50LWRpc3Bvc2l0aW9uPWF0dGFjaG1lbnQlM0JmaWxlbmFtZSUzRCUyMnRyb3ZlNGotMjAxNjA4MjQuamFyJTIyIiwiQ29uZGl0aW9uIjp7IkRhdGVMZXNzVGhhbiI6eyJBV1M6RXBvY2hUaW1lIjoxNTk5ODM1NDA5fSwiSXBBZGRyZXNzIjp7IkFXUzpTb3VyY2VJcCI6IjAuMC4wLjAvMCJ9fX1dfQ__&Signature=i5ZoEIAPPZFtbRtYD9XkEorS92VRPkcA418YNn7tpH5k7Puf9~IPnFrmzhvLnXkfBC455E3iTaQ~6DJeUdAQJ6GaDyY3SRAfhvtNBCEcGUj-WTnbx3SfWAjZnMOPVZJYvJ7g~sRTPq9wU1kpnWAYlfDR0kv2Hdtr597uQtXlkGQvfATh2D~-mBkvKuTurxPXKit7~S6Dx6r4VMA~P00wUbB6oWKUOhPxhZwTWrHYDU3Akiuz9d5zXVNWn7G28f3Sx6feX7sHWlExseebGihNp9-UazJ6a4A8oyjfwT7KA4Bizr5nOd1I2YRePyF7vVuE~I48JAfh88cUClLWPtz-Aw__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFKFWOMXM2UMTSFA'.
                > Connection reset
    
    * Try:
    Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Exception is:
    org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'My Application 0003'.
    
    ...
    
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    
    BUILD FAILED in 3s
```

Контент build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.10"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Прокси сервера в локали и в браузере нет.

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл решение самостоятельно. Перебрав кучу комбинаций репозиториев, заработала вот такая:

```
google()
maven{url 'http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/'}
jcenter()
```

Comment: Спасибо, братишка! Выручил. Я целый день над этим просидел, да и куча народа пыталась в разные годы. Просто сейчас будет переезд на Maven, так что ответ пригодится.

Comment: Опубликую пока на https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49573157/android-studio-3-1-could-not-find-org-jetbrains-trove4jtrove4j20160824/66168563. Держи +20, ни в чём себе не отказывай.

Comment: Лучше заменить на `https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/`.